# Find word in string solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, dapp-design

How is it possible to look for if a certain word is part of a string in solidity? let's say someone upload a string to a smart contract, this string must contain the word "solidity" to be accepted by a function. Is it possible to create a modifier or require() check that ensures this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```solidity
modifier contains (string memory what, string memory where) {
    bytes memory whatBytes = bytes (what);
    bytes memory whereBytes = bytes (where);

    require(whereBytes.length >= whatBytes.length);

    bool found = false;
    for (uint i = 0; i <= whereBytes.length - whatBytes.length; i++) {
        bool flag = true;
        for (uint j = 0; j < whatBytes.length; j++)
            if (whereBytes [i + j] != whatBytes [j]) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        if (flag) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    require (found);

    _;
}

function foo (string memory str) public contains ("solidity", str) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're a legend, your inputs are always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This repository include a function that find a word into a string and the number of repetitions.

https://github.com/HermesAteneo/solidity-repeated-word-in-string

Hope it helps