# Solidity (find a word in a string and replace it)

Tags: solidity, string, bytes

I am learning solidity string/byte manipulation and I am trying to create a Solidity function that finds specific words in a string/format and replaces them with given variables to return "edited" string

Example:

```
string format = "UserData: {address}, {balance}"

function replaceWords(string calldata Format) external pure returns (string memory){

   address addr = 0x8599fed66e2a440f12e9bc3fcf40594af78f3694;
   unit balance = 100;
   string memory editedString;


   // Function logic


   return editedString //Returns "UserData: 0x8599fed66e2a440f12e9bc3fcf40594af78f3694, 100" 

}
```

The function should also work if the "format" is arranged differently.
Example: "UserData: {balance}, {address}" ---> returns: "UserData: 100, 0x8599fed66e2a440f12e9bc3fcf40594af78f3694"

I did find some similar examples but I am not 100% sure how should I approach this.

[find-word-in-string-solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69307/find-word-in-string-solidity)

[solidity-how-to-replace-specific-string-position-with-letter](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73595/solidity-how-to-replace-specific-string-position-with-letter)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See Nick Johnson's [solidity-stringutils](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Thanks for the advice, but when I am trying to import the lib I get an error (ParserError: Source file requires a different compiler version). In short, the lib seems to be 3-4 years outdated (using 0.4.14). While I am using 0.8.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solady's [`LibString`](https://github.com/Vectorized/solady/blob/2c7fa305e443b0e69abff24810dc814a9202f966/src/utils/LibString.sol) has a [`replace`](https://github.com/Vectorized/solady/blob/2c7fa305e443b0e69abff24810dc814a9202f966/src/utils/LibString.sol#L354) method:

```
function replace(string memory subject, string memory search, string memory replacement)
    internal
    pure
    returns (string memory result)
{
    // --- snip --- //
}
```